# Firebase admin SDK database update returns undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm updating my database with Firebase Admin SDK like so:

```
admin.database().ref(`clients/${id}`).update({name: 'name'})
.then(snapshot => console.log(snapshot))
```

However, it logs `undefined`. Any ideas why this could be?

```
"firebase-admin": "^9.12.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Promise returned by the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#update) method does not contain the snapshot of the node you've just updated.

You need to re-query the RTDB to get the value of the node, as follows:

```
const dbRef = admin.database().ref(`clients/${id}`);
dbRef.update({name: 'name'})
.then(() => {
   return dbRef.get();
})
.then(snapshot => {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Would the `set` method return the snapshot? Because I tested it with the `set` method, and it returns `undefined` as well, but only in cases when I `set` on an existing entry in the DB; if I create a new object with `set`, it does indeed return the snapshot of the node. Is this by design?

Comment: I don’t think the  `set()` method returns a non void Promise. I cannot test it at the moment but I think the behaviour is the same than the `update()` method.

Comment: You're right. I found a false positive in my code which made me think `set()` actually returned an object. Upon further testing, I cannot reproduce that. Thanks for the insights! :)